# Print smallest value then highest value

Tags: c#, console

Input

```
[1,5,3,7,2,10,15,9]
```

Output

```
[1,15,2,10,3,9,5,7]
```

The logic is `[1st smallest value, 1st highest value, 2nd smallest value, 2nd highest value, ...]`

How to implement this in C#?

Comment: What have you got so far? And where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SmallestGreatestSequence<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var ordered = source.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
    var ascendingIndex = 0;
    var descendingIndex = ordered.Count - 1;

    while (ascendingIndex < descendingIndex)
    {
        yield return ordered[ascendingIndex++];
        yield return ordered[descendingIndex--];
    }

    if (ascendingIndex == descendingIndex)
        yield return ordered[ascendingIndex];
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
var someArray = new[] { 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 10, 15, 9 };
var sortedArray = someArray.SmallestGreatestSequence().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with a LINQ based solution, below may be an option.

```
var input = new int[] { 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 10, 15, 9, 6 };

var sorted = input
    .OrderBy(z => z)
    .ToList();

var zippedInOrder = sorted.Take(input.Length / 2)
                        .Zip(
                            Enumerable.Reverse(sorted).Take(input.Length / 2),
                            (a, b) => new int[] { a, b });

var inOrder = zippedInOrder.SelectMany(z => z);

if (input.Length % 2 == 1)
{
    // Add the 'middle' element (sort order wise) 
    inOrder = inOrder.Concat(new List<int> { sorted[input.Length / 2] });
}

var finalInOrder = inOrder.ToList();

// To test
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", finalInOrder));
```

The code sorts the input data, then takes the low numbers and `Zip`s them with the large numbers. Then `SelectMany` is used to project the data into a single `IEnumerable`. And `Concat` is used to add the leftover middle item (if the `Length` was odd).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is SQL or MySQL related, but as the first tag is C#, here is a solution for that:

```
var inputSorted = input.OrderBy( i => i ).ToArray();
var output = new List<int>();

//go with index to the half of the array
for ( int i = 0; i < inputSorted.Length / 2; i++ )
{
   //add the i-th lowest number
   output.Add( inputSorted[i] );
   //add the i-th highest number
   output.Add( inputSorted[inputSorted.Length - i - 1] );
}

//if the length of the array is odd, add the single left out number
if ( inputSorted.Length % 2 == 1 )
{
   output.Add( inputSorted[inputSorted.Length / 2] );
}
```

Comment: the name 'input' doesn't  exit in current code.

how this error remove this program. am a beginner so please don't mind.